# ImageView GridView bad order and bad performance

Tags: android, gridview

If I have (1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8) images in GridView show - > (1)(2)(3)(4)(1)(2)(3)(4) which this code and this work which very good performance.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;

            if (convertView == null) {//here
                // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300, 300));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

                File imgFile = new File(ImagesApi.getCalculatedList().get(
                        position));

                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile
                        .getAbsolutePath());


                imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap,
                        (int) (myBitmap.getWidth() * 0.12),
                        (int) (myBitmap.getHeight() * 0.12), true));

                myBitmap.recycle();

            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            return imageView;
     }

    public int getCount() {
        return ImagesApi.getCalculatedList().size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

If I add `if (convertView == null || position != convertView.getId()) {` and `imageView.setId(position);` in "//here" I get images in GridView which correct order but which very very bad performance. Ui thread go very very slow.

`ImagesApi.getCalculatedList()` is **constant** ArrayList of image paths